# Generate C wrapper from C++?

Tags: c++, c, wrapper, ffi

I want to generate C wrappers from C++ libraries. 
There are tutorials on how to do it by hand:

- http://dsc.sun.com/solaris/articles/mixing.html
- http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html

But it is too much of a manual labor.

For example, for this:

```
struct RtAudio {
    virtual DeviceInfo const& f() {...}
    class DeviceInfo {
        virtual void g() { ... }
    };
    ...
};
```

I need to write:

```
struct RtAudioC {
    RtAudio x;
};
struct DeviceInfo {
    RtAudio::DeviceInfo x;
};
extern "C" {
    RtAudioC* newRtAudio() { 
        return new RtAudioC;
    }
    void deleteRtAudio(RtAudioC *p {
        delete p;
    }
    /* do something with RtAudio::f() */
    void g(DeviceInfo *p) {
        try {
            p->x.g();
        } catch (SomeError & err) {
        }
    }
}
```

Are there tools that can automate this process?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/), C code generator was last year's GSoC project. AFAIK they haven't merged it to the trunk yet, so you'd have to checkout & build the branch from SVN.

Answer (score 2):

I just developed a C function wrapper in Python to do exactly this (generate C++ classes that wrap C functions).

It's still young but the bulk of what I needed it to do is in there now.  Give it a try and let me know what you think: https://github.com/mlb5000/CFunctionWrapperGenerator

Answer (score 1):

There is gmmproc which creates C++ wrappers for gobject based C libraries, but that's the only code generator I've heard of between C and C++.

If you're good with writing a parser, it wouldn't be too difficult a task to create a basic wrapper generator. In the end you might have to add a few finishing touches manually, but still your work load would be reduced.

Answer (score 1):

How much of your C++ code is already written vs. how much has yet to be written?
If a reasonable proportion is to-be-written, I would create a simplified syntax, that generates both the C++ and C headers, like IDL does for COM interfaces.  This simplified syntax will be much easier for you to parse than C++, or you can likely find something off the shelf that does this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an off-the-shelf tool to do this.  If you want to automate the generation and are happy to write your own scripts, [pygccxml](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygccxml/0.6.9) (based on [GCC-XML](http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/Index.html)) is quite a nice way to parse C++ headers.